# string builder replacing the selected item in a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have list view that when double clicks inserts the selected item into a textbox, however the inserted value has to be different from the the selected item. For example the 'Customer Name' is easier to read but is displayed as `##CustomerName##` in the textbox.

```
.Replace("Customer Name", "##CUSTOMERNAME##")
.Replace("Customer Name", "##CUSTOMERNAME##")
.Replace("Customer Name", "##CUSTOMERNAME##")
.Replace("Customer Name", "##CUSTOMERNAME##")
.Replace("Customer Name", "##CUSTOMERNAME##")
```

Is their a better approach than doing this 90 times? I thought about assigning the `##CUSTOMERNAME##` tag in the list view, then selecting the tag.

Comment: Implement your stuff in a MVVM way and do all the things in your view model.

Comment: @dymanoid i am still learning, do you have any useful learning material on MVVM? something for beginners?

Comment: You can start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).